# Why is getApplication information reset after picking a picture?

Tags: android-intent, android

I have an abstract activity called `AbstractEntryActivity`. Two activities `ModifyEntryActivity` and `AddEntryActivity` extend it.

I also have a global `Application` that I call with `getApplication`, and where I put information which should be global. A **list**, in my case.

In my abstract activity, I call an intent to take or pick a picture like that :

```
public void onPickPicture(View view) {

    Intent pickIntent = new Intent();
    pickIntent.setType("image/*");
    pickIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent,
            getString(R.string.dialog_pick_picture_title));
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
            new Intent[] { takePhotoIntent });

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, Constants.SELECT_PICTURE);
}
```

I also have a method `onActivityResult` which deals with the picture. But before being called, the method `onCreate` is called. *(Sometimes, onActivityResult is called and not onCreate)*

On the first `onCreate` call of my Abstract Activity, I check the content of the list of my application: it is ok (neither null, nor empty).
Now, when I come back from the gallery, I call getApplication, and the List that I put in it is null.

Here is my `onCreate` from the Abstract activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_entry);
   // Get all views ...
   ...
   mApp = (MyApplication) getApplication();
   Log.d(TAG, "mApp = "+mApp);
   Log.d(TAG, "mApp.getList() = "+mApp.getList()); // HERE it is NULL on 2nd call
   // Init date
   initDate();
   // Init all fields
   initFields() ;
   // getSupportActionBar
   ...
}
```

What I don't understand is :

- On both `AddEntryActivity` and `ModifyEntryActivity`, the onCreate is the same (a simple call to super.onCreate)
- On `ModifyEntryActivity`, I get mApp.getList = null on the second call
- It seems that most of the time, in `AddEntryActivity`, mApp.getList returns the right value. *Wait, I tried again, and that's not always the case*

I really don't understand what is going on here, and why it does not always behave the same.
I don't know exactly what I changed, but before today, it was working correctly.

N.B. If I **don't** change the picture, everything is fine, and the entry is added/modified correctly

Could you help me find what is wrong, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong.

When I launched the intent to take/pick a picture, I actually left the application (which I assume was killed), and when I went back to it, the application retrieved by `getApplication` was once again clear of all values.

In order to fix that, I had to override the method `onSaveInstanceState` in order to put the values of my list in it - and retrieve the values in either `onCreate`or in `onRestoreInstanceState`. After that, I could once again set the list in my application with `getApplication().setList(myRetrievedList)`. For the record, I put the overriding methods in the abstract activity.

As the data I wanted to keep was a custom list, I had to make it implement `Parcelable`, so that I could put it in the bundle.

*I don't know if it is the best way to deal with that, so feel free to propose a better solution, if any.*